# Rails user login is invalid without error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making user registration and login function, based on Rails console, I know that I can successfully register user. However, logging in as a user (pressing the login button) does nothing. The terminal log shows "[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do" and follows:

"Redirected to [http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in"](http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in%22)

"Filter chain halted as :check_login! rendered or redirected"

"Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 599)"

After I manually moved to the list page, it was confirmed that the login was unsuccessful. I'm not relying on Devise for a membership system and I'm not sure what's wrong. Originally I guessed that it was the problem of `redirect_to` after logging in, but it was not after testing.

This is part of the Route

```
  post "/users/sign_in", to: "sessions#create", as: "login"
  delete "/users", to: "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
```

This is SessionsController, log in as `def create`, log out as `def destroy`

```
require 'digest'

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_login!, except: [:index, :show]

  def create
      pw = user_params[:password]
      salted_pw = "eiojre#{pw}rewropwr"
      hashed_password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(salted_pw)
      user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:email],
                              password: hashed_password)
      if user
        session[:random2022] = user.id
        redirect_to recipes_path
      else
        redirect_to "/users/sign_in", :notice => I18n.t(:user_pw_wrong)
      end
  end

  def destroy
      session[:random2022] = nil
      redirect_to "/"
    end
            
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end

end
```

This is part of UsersController

```
  def sign_in
    @user = User.new
  end

  def sign_up
    @user = User.new
  end
```

This is the View of the login page

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<div class="col">
  <%= form_for(@user, url: login_path) do |f| %>
    <div>
      <label>
        <%= f.label "Email" %>
      </label><br>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>
        <%= f.label "Password" %>
      </label><br>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Login" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I found the same situation with sign_up

Comment: SHA1 was cryptographically broken many many years ago and is trivial to brute force with modern hardware. It should not be used for password encryption. Using a fixed salt thats written into your code together with the password defeats even the trivial amount of safety that a secret salt provides. This is not how you do password encryption.

Comment: Instead use [`has_secure_password`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) which uses Bcrypt for password encryption.

Comment: Besides the huge security flaws you need to remove the `before_action :check_login!, except: [:index, :show]` as thats whats causing the redirect. The callback is fired before you actually log the user in.